# Good customization tutorials for Dynamics CRM that are NOT sales driven

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, customization

I'm brand new to Dynamics CRM and have been asked to see if this is a viable replacement for the employee tracking software we're using now (AlexSys Team 2 Pro). We're not so much of a sales based company as the tutorials i see for CRM focus on. I know CRM is more for customer relations and sales tracking but i also know it's highly customizable and can do what i need it to do. I need something that keeps track of how many new tasks have been created and how many have been done and to show a graph or a report with the results. I've looked at some PluralSight videos and some windows videos but they all seem to focus on and really push the use of its sales side usability. We do sell our product here (i work at a software development company) but we need something that isn't focused on sales and is usable to management for tracking progress. So for example, lets say im aksed to do 4 things(tasks), I do 2 of those things and am in the process of handling my 3rd. I'm not a sales agent, lets say im a programmer, I need CRM to be able to show my manager that I had 4 new tasks, completed 2, and if possible to show that im in the process of working on the 3rd. AlexSys Team gives you different options for what state the task is in, such as In-Process and Completed but it does poorly when it comes to reporting. Are there any good places to learn how to do that in CRM, we are not using a partner and will not have someone coding this or changing this for us, i will possibly be the one working on that so i need something that can help show me how to customize it without constantly talking about sales. Im off to watch more PluralSight videos but maybe a user here knows of somewhere better to learn from or maybe just a specific PluralSight video i may have missed. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamics CRM is as you've discovered very customisable and will almost certainly meet the requirements you've described.  Whether it is the correct choice only you can decide.

YouTube is a really good resource for CRM videos, you can also take a look at the [CRM 2011 Technical Training Videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/DynamicsCRM2011) on Channel 9 produced when the product was first released.  These give a high level overview of CRM 2011 technical capabilities.

You may want to look at the basics of Activities ( in particular Tasks ) and Queues.  Make sure you're clear on the usage of Status and Status Reason and how you can customise them.  For reporting you can either use the built-in dashboard capabilities or create your own SSRS reports using BIDS that can be hosted within CRM.  The process of producing these reports whilst subtlety different will be easily understood by anyone with some some basic SSRS skills.

I'd recommend enlisting the help of a partner in the first instance even if it's to just verify your initial design.  The overall cost of their time in relation to the install and running costs of CRM won't be too significant and they may even be able to save you some money.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of a better place for videos, but I can speak to CRM's ability to serve as a rapid application development platform and the areas it excels.  It allows you to create new fields and entities (think Database Tables) without touching a database, as well as customize forms, roles, and security with 0 code.  You can also sign up for a [free months trial online](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-free-trial-overview.aspx) to setup a quick Proof of Concept.

There is so much that it can do, and do quickly, that your company may be better served to seek outside help, resulting in a better product, delivered quicker, with less overall costs than trying to do everything "in-house".